# Динамическая отрисовка таблице в реальном времени

Tags: javascript, websocket

Не могу сообразить.

```
<table id="table"></table>
<script>
var r = new RegExp("\x27+","g");
var str = "[[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' '],[' ',' ',' ']]"; // переменная находится во внешнем файле

var min_map = str.replace(r, "\x22"); // тут я меняю кавычки на двойные, потому что с сервера должен придти ответ с одинарными.

var table = document.querySelector('#table');
var arr = JSON.parse(min_map);

fillTable(table, arr);

function fillTable(table, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement('tr');

        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerHTML = arr[i][j];
            tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        table.appendChild(tr);
    }
}
```

Вобщем в куске сверху, происходит генерация таблицы из строки JSON.

Переменная str меняет своё значение, новым, полученным из websocket. С этим вроде всё путём.
Но моя таблица отрисовывает только первое состояние переменной. 
Как можно отловить изменения в переменной и перерисовать table?

---

похоже я вообще не верно задал вопрос ) Я контоллирую внешний файл. дело немного в другом. когда переменная меняется, на странице (в table) добавляется(!) её новое значение. то есть моя таблица разрастается с каждым новым запросом. Мне нужно чтобы содержимое 'id table' менялось на новуюс сформированую таблицу

---

ещё понятнее:
вот так обстоят дела -

```
table
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]   __ запрос
[s][o][h]
[k][h][g]
[d][t][y]
```

как должно это выглядеть :

```
table
[1][2][3]
[4][5][6]
[7][8][9]  ___запрос

table
[s][o][h]
[k][h][g]
[d][t][y]
```

То есть каждый запрос, матрица должна обновлятся, не перезагружая страницу, не наращивая ячейки в таблице.

зы
блин почему текст жирный?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы не контролируете код, который назначает переменную `str`, заведите таймер (`setInterval`) и сравнивайте текущее значение переменной с сохраненным старым.

---

```
function fillTable(table, arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  // delete old rows: table.innerHTML = "";
  var oldRows = table.querySelectorAll("tr");
  for (var i = 0; i < oldRows.length; i++) {
    oldRows[i].parentNode.removeChild(oldRows[i]);
  }
  // add new rows:
  ...
    td.innerHTML = arr[i][j]; // может быть td.textContent = arr[i][j]; ? 
  ...
}
```

Comment: Не работает, к сожалению. Таблица не растёт... Вообще ничего не происходит. В логах str меняется, но с таблицей ничего не происходит. Она находится в первоначальном состоянии. Пробовал вешать onclick с вызовом функции, тоже безрезультатно.

Comment: @Smile Я не понял. Вы хотите, чтобы таблица росла, или не хотите? Где вызывается `fillTable` с новым содержимым?

Comment: @Smile Добавьте `console.log(arr);` как в ответе. В консоли браузера данные появляются?

Comment: нет. табличка расти не должна ) Происходит следующее: при запуске странички, формируется таблица из переменной str и остаётся статичной. У меня навешен console.log(str); на переменную, в консоли я вижу что переменная меняется. Я вызываю     <input value="Click" onclick="ws.send(ts); fillTable(table, arr);" type="button"><br/> Прямой вызов не срабатывает. Таблица не изменяется, ошибок в консоли нет.

Comment: @Smile Вы добавили `console.log(arr);` в функцию? Подозреваю, что Вы передаете туда одно и то же `arr`.

Comment: я похоже нашёл эту дырку. я вызываю функцию с отпарсеным аргументом: var arr = JSON.parse(min_map); а он остаётся неизменным с первой генерации... Сори, был невнимателен.

Comment: именно так и происходит )